# How do you index records even if some of the columns are nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am using sunspot/solr for search. I recently found that some records were not being indexed because a column sometimes had nil values.

How I can I tell solr to index these records regardless?

This is what my searchable block looks like:

```
  searchable do
    text :name
    text :description
    # this price_as_double can sometimes be nil
    double :price_as_decimal
    text :colors do
      colors.map(&:name)
    end
    text :store do
      unless store.nil?
        store.name
      end
    end
    string :store do
      unless store.nil?
        store.name
      end
    end
    text :items_style do
      unless items_style.nil?
        items_style.name
      end
    end
    time :created_at
    boolean :editors_pick
    string :sold_out
    double :likes
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

For rails you need to add following function into migration

```
def change
   add_column :product, :price, :string
   add_index :product, :price
end
```

Your migration will work and will allow multiply null values (for the most database engines).

But your validation for the product class should look like below.

validates :price, allow_nil: true

Answer (score 0):

Your `unless` statements are preventing the objects from being indexed when some of the attributes are `nil`. A better way would be do have something like this:

```
searchable do
  text :name
  text :description
  # this price_as_double can sometimes be nil
  double :price_as_decimal
  text :colors do
    colors.map(&:name)
  end
  text :store do
    store.present? ? store.name : ''
  end
  string :store do
    store.present? ? store.name : ''
  end
  text :items_style do
    items_style.present? ? items_style.name : ''
  end
  time :created_at
  boolean :editors_pick
  string :sold_out
  double :likes
end
```

Where if the values are `nil` (or blank), an empty string gets indexed instead.